# AMQ9631E: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, openshift, ibm-mq

Attempts to connect to IBM MQ queues.

Below is the code responsible for creating the connection:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
IConnection connectionMQ;

factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);
IConnectionFactory cf = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, "host");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, port);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, "channel");
cf.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, "queueManager"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_PEER_NAME, "sslPeerName"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SPEC, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256"); 
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CCSID, "ccSid");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "*USER");
cf.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SSL_CLIENT_CERT_LABEL, "clientCertLabel");

connectionMQ = cf.CreateConnection();
```

Error visible on the server side:

> AMQ9631E: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not
> match the required CipherSpec for channel 'channel'.
>
> EXPLANATION: There is a mismatch between the CipherSpecs on the local
> and remote ends of channel 'channel'. The channel will not run until
> this mismatch is resolved. The CipherSpec required in the local
> channel definition is 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256'. The name of
> the CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake is
> 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'. A code is displayed if the name of
> the negotiated CipherSpec cannot be determined. ACTION: Change the
> channel definitions for 'channel' so the two ends have matching
> CipherSpecs and restart the channel. When using the 'ANY' type
> CipherSpecs ensure that the Client CipherSpec value would meet the
> requirements for the 'TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256' CipherSpec set
> on the channel 'channel'. If the client is set to use the 'ANY' type
> CipherSpecs  then the TLS handshake may use a higher protocol than is
> allowed by the channel channel definition CipherSpec. If the
> certificate in use by one end of the channel is a Global Server
> Certificate, then the negotiated CipherSpec may not match that
> specified on either end of the channel. This is because the SSL
> protocol allows a Global Server Certificate to automatically negotiate
> a higher level of encryption. In these cases specify a CipherSpec
> which meets the requirements of the Global Server Certificate.

Why, despite the fact that via .net I pass TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, you can see TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 in the server-side logs?

Client is on redhat.

Comment: @JoshMc I don't know if the server is windows, client is osh (redhat). Is the error on the server or client side?

Comment: It is not an error, working as designed. In manged mode .net it only uses the cipher you specify to find the version to use (for example TLSv1.2), it will then negotiate to the most preferred cipher between the MQ Client and the queue manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IBM MQ/XMS .NET Clients, the Cipher Set at the application level is used to determine the TLS version only.
**Client Running on Windows:** IBM MQ/XMS .NET client rely on the Microsoft's SSLStreams for SSL Communication.To set a preferred Cipher the Windows Group Policy has to be enabled and edited to use a specific Cipher. After it is enabled and edited the machine has to be restarted to pickup the changes. Please note that the change in the Windows Group Policy is applicable to all the applications running on the Machine.

Following KC page has more information on it
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.1?topic=client-cipherspec-support-managed-net

**For a client running on Linux**
On Linux .NET uses openssl for SSL Communications, so to set the CipherSpec preferences the Openssl config file has to be edited

Comment: I don't know if the server is windows, client is osh (redhat). Is the error on the server or client side?

Comment: @KillerQueen: The above answer was for a Client running on Windows.For a Client running on Linux, .NET uses OpenSSL for SSL Communications, hence openssl config file must be edited to set the preference of CipherSpec.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and followed few IBM MQ support articles to resolve the problem. Our C#.Net application was using IBM MQ .Net Client version 8 and queue manager was less than v9.2. One fine day server admins upgraded to 9.2 and our application started receiving AMQ9631E: The CipherSpec negotiated during the SSL handshake does not match the required CipherSpec for channel 'channel name'. Our application was connecting to a Channel over TLS1.2 and Cipher Spec was TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256. We followed below two articles to solve our problem. Please note our application is hosted on Windows server 2016 and the default TLS version is TLS 1.2 . Also please note that other java application running on Linux servers were able to connect without any change.

1. [TLS Cipher Specification Order Changed in MQ 9.2](https://web.archive.org/web/20231007165637/https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/tls-cipher-specification-order-changed-mq-92)
2. [CipherSpec order in TLS handshake](https://web.archive.org/web/20220810200230/https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=cipherspecs-cipherspec-order-in-tls-handshake)

Exact steps that we followed:

Server admins created a new channel with Cipher Spec TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384. We started using this new channel for connection but then faced another issue. [Comp code 2 Reason code 2538 suggesting {client and Server cannot communicate, because they do not conatain same algorithm }].

To solve above we did below and fixed the issue.
Upgraded Client application to use IBMMQDotnetClient v9.3. and used .net standard dll for .Net Framework 4.8 . If you are on core you can use core packages available.